# Do persistent class properties forming composite key also need to be serializable or transient in case of non-serializable?

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, transient

I have a persistent class :

```
public class NotifEventGroupRel implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7616645672995663305L;
    private Long eventGroupId;
    private String eventName;

    private NotifEventGroup notifEventGroup; //// composite id property
    private EmailTmplt emailTmplt;   // composite id property
    private SmsTmplt smsTmplt;       // composite id property
 ....
}
```

Its hbm.xml file is :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="NotifEventGroupRel" table="TBLMEVENTGROUPREL">
    <composite-id>
                <key-many-to-one name="notifEventGroup" class="NotifEventGroup" lazy="false" >
                    <column name="EVENTGROUPID" precision="20" scale="0" not-null="true" />
                </key-many-to-one>
                <key-property name="eventName" type="java.lang.String">
                    <column name="EVENT" />
                </key-property>
    </composite-id>
<many-to-one name="emailTmplt" class="EmailTmplt" lazy="false" not-null="false" >
            <column name="EMAILTMPLTID"></column>
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="smsTmplt" class="SmsTmplt" lazy="false" not-null="false">
            <column name="SMSTMPLTID" />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The class of properties forming composite id is :

```
public class NotifEventGroup {

        private Long eventGroupId;
        private String name;
.......
}


public class EmailTmplt {
    private Long emailTmpltId;
    private String name;
.....   
}

public class SmsTmplt {
    private Long smsTmpltId;
    private String name;
..........
}
```

- Do i need to make following properties transient :

(shown below)

```
private transient NotifEventGroup notifEventGroup; //// composite id property
private transient EmailTmplt emailTmplt;   // composite id property
private transient SmsTmplt smsTmplt;       // composite id property
```

because findbug gives me **`Non-transient non-serializable instance field in serializable class`** error for the fields (if non transient).

- OR do i have to make their corresponding class serializable ?

And what is the impact of doing any of the above two cases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is reported because all fields in class implementing `Serializable` must also be `Serializable`.

### Making fields transient

Making fields `transient` means that they should be ignored in serialization, and I think you don't want that (because they are included in hibernate-mapping file).

From the Java Language Specification, [Java SE 7 Edition, Section 8.3.1.3.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3) transient Fields:

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object.

### Making classes implement Serializable

The classes `NotifEventGroup`, `EmailTmplt` and `SmsTmplt` should also implement `Serializable`-interface. Implementing `Serializable` actually does nothing, it is just a marker interface for notifying users that the class can be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that these 3 classes are not serializable now. After all, they are entities, too, so why haven't you made them serializable? If you make them transient, Hibernate will not save them – I doubt you'd want such behaviour, esp. in key fields.